# Оповещение JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста. Мозила, Опера, Хром выдают: Error loading language file file:///D:/MySite/yoxview/lang/en.js, IE9 - все нормально. Спасибо.

Comment: вы облегчите нашу задачу, если укажете релевантную часть исходников.

Comment: Спасибо. Но подскажите пожалуйста где мне это исправить.

Comment: если я правильно понял: верхняя часть html кода?

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте `file://`, используйте `http://`. Браузеры ограничивают доступ к ресурсам из кода js.

Comment: Если проблема действительно в этом, тогда уж лучше использовать просто `//path`